# seteuid fails even when all UIDs are 0

Tags: linux, permissions, c, c++, setuid

I have some C++ code on a Linux machine whose purpose is to run some code as an arbitrary user.

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void doAsUser(uid_t uid) {
    if (CAP_IS_SUPPORTED(CAP_SETUID)) {
        cout << "Do we have CAP_SETUID? " << cap_get_bound(CAP_SETUID) << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "CAP_SETUID not supported!" << endl;
    }

    uid_t ruid, euid, suid;
    getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
    cout << "UIDs: " << ruid << " " << euid << " " << suid << endl;

    // assume credentials of user
    status = seteuid(uid);
    if (status < 0) {
        cerr << "FATAL ERROR: Couldn't set uid: " <<  strerror(errno) << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // do stuff here...

    // re-assume credentials of program
    status = seteuid(my_uid);
    if (status < 0) {
        cerr << "FATAL ERROR: Couldn't reset uid: " <<  strerror(errno) << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

However, without fail, you get the following output when this function is run:

```
$ sudo ./program
```

...

```
Do we have CAP_SETUID? 1
UIDs: 0 0 0
FATAL ERROR: Couldn't set uid: Operation not permitted
```

What's going on here? I thought things running as root (you know, with UID 0 and CAP_SETUID) could assume effective UIDs of any other user.

EDIT: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399746/what-is-required-by-a-process-to-set-its-uid-to-0-root) does not adequately answer my problem, because, as it states, "In order to perform the call to `seteuid` even though the EUID at the time is not 0, the SUID must be 0". My SUID is 0, my CAP_SETUID is 1, and I have no other security framework in place.

Comment: I have found a solution to this and would like to post an answer. Could you please unmark this as a duplicate?

Comment: Thank you for instrumenting your routine.  Now, could you please take it a step further and modify the code to print the value of “`uid`” (the argument to the function), just in case it is some weird, invalid value?  And, maybe, to be paranoid, print the return values of `getuid`, `geteuid` and `getresuid`.  Note that your current code won’t even *compile,* since you are still using **`my_uid`** even though you have deleted its declaration, and you have never showed us a declaration for `status` (please don’t tell me that it’s a global variable).

Comment: Um, doesn't `cap_get_bound()` just check the bounding set? Don't you need to check the effective capabilities instead?

Comment: @Iconmaster what was your solution?