# What is the history of /etc/mtab and what updated it?

Tags: linux, mount, history

I updated an old linux boot disk with new utilities and shared libraries.  It still had an empty `/etc/mtab` to start with, on the old disk the `/etc/mtab` was updated, on the new one `/etc/mtab` stayed zero.  I see now we link `/etc/mtab` to `/proc/mounts` but question remains:

1. What was updating `/etc/mtab` to keep it up to date?
2. When did it change from `/etc/mtab` to `/proc/mounts`
3. How do we keep up on all the fundamental changes that occur in linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On systems where `/etc/mtab` is a regular file, updating `/etc/mtab` is the job of the `mount` and `umount` commands. In addition, boot scripts update `/etc/mtab` once the root filesystem is mounted read-write, either by extracting information from `/proc/mounts` or by writing what the boot scripts know about what they've already mounted.

For a long time, there was a debate about whether `/etc/mtab` should be a regular file or a symlink to `/proc/mounts`. Making it a regular file has the downside that it could get out of sync with the system state (for example if the root filesystem was read-only during a mount or unmount operation). It also doesn't accommodate modern features such as mount [namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92177/kernel-namespaces-support), where processes might not see the same mount points even if they see the same `/etc/mtab`. But making it a symlink to `/proc/mounts` had the downside that the kernel used to not report all the information one would like to have:

- The kernel used to hide default mount options, but the defaults depended on the kernel version, so it was hard to figure out the exact mount options from `/proc/mounts`, whereas `/etc/mtab` gave you exactly what was passed to the `mount` command.
- The kernel used to report [bind mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) as copies of the original mount, and not as bind mounts.

Modern kernels report more information through `/etc/mounts` so there is no longer a reason to prefer making `/etc/mtab` a regular file.

[Debian bug #494001](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=494001) is when Debian stopped maintaining `/etc/mtab` as a regular file. Highlights from that thread (I haven't verified the accuracy, but I have no reason to doubt):

- The relevant part of the thread is mostly the initial message. The rest is mostly about concerns related to the transition.
- “With linux >= 2.6.26, /proc/mounts contains all of the information in
  /etc/mtab, plus more”.
- The [attached patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=494001;filename=sysvinit-mtab-diff;msg=27) contains the last version of the code to update `/etc/mtab` (`/etc/init.d/mtab.sh`).

> How do we keep up on all the fundamental changes that occur in linux?

Good luck with that… Everybody has a different set of changes they consider fundamental. All of it must have appeared on [LWN (Linux Weekly News)](https://lwn.net/), but that's very high-traffic and includes discussions of proposed upcoming changes.